# Las peticiones de sub-recursos que usan protocolos ftp estan obsoletas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ftp

buenas , tengo el siguiente problema:

al entrar en el modulo de productos de mi plataforma(con protocolo HTTPS) 
y consultar un producto, la información que me devuelve el web service 
es el detalle del producto, en el cual viene un campo llamado imagen 
que tiene la ruta ftp de la imagen

"ftp://user:password@domain/ruta/imagen.png"

todo esto sale perfecto, pero google chrome me avisa de esto:

```
[Deprecation] Subresource requests using legacy protocols (like `ftp:`) are deprecated, and will be blocked in M59, around June 2017. Please deliver web-accessible resources over modern protocols like HTTPS. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5709390967472128 for more details.
```

esto supone un problema  futuro para mi plataforma, ya que la las imagenes la guardo en un servidor ftp para que no me ocupen espacio en el servidor

agradeceria muchisimo una solucion a mi problema , de antemano muchas gracias. 
no creo que sea necesario poner código, pues todo esta bien , estoy trabajando en php y javascript para esa parte !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solución a mi problema:

a la final descargue la imagen,pero sin guardarla en mi servidor , utilice la función file_get_contents de php, luego codifique  el string que me devuelve dicha función a base64 y luego en el atributo src de la etiqueta IMG puse data:image/jpg;base64 ,   como no pesan tanto y la consulta es asíncrona funciona, aquí el código por si alguien lo necesita:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('ftp' => array('header'=>'Connection: close\r\n')));
$Imagen = file_get_contents($entry->Ruta, false, $context);
$imageData = base64_encode($Imagen);

echo '<img  id="ImgProd'.$i.'" src="data:image/jpg;base64,".$imageData." style="height:auto; max-width: 90%; border-radius: 5px;" class="form-control" name="sImagen"/>';
```

esto funciona para mi, pues a lo que una descarga termina se muestra la imagen al instante mientras las otras imágenes se van descargando y asi sucesivamente.
gracias a los que comentaron y aportaron ideas !!

Answer (score 0):

Los mas sencillo: utiliza un *proxy* PHP, que convierta peticiones HTTP en peticiones FTP.

No es necesario que manejes el protocolo FTP por completo. Puedes usar la función `ftp_get( )`, que te *libera* de todo el trabajo.

La idea es sencilla: creas un archivo `ftp.php` que se limite a obtener el archivo que le pasan como parámetro, y lo envíe por la propia salida de PHP. En la [documentación oficial de ftp_get( )](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ftp-get.php) tienes varios ejemplos sobre ello.

Este esquema presenta **2** inconvenientes:

1. Latencia. Las peticiones FTP tienen un protocolo mas complejo que el HTTP, por lo que el tiempo en satisfacer la petición es mayor.
2. **Todo** pasa por PHP. **No** podrás aprovechar ningún mecanismo de *cache* del servidor, lo que implica un mayor uso de recursos, y una menor velocidad ( que se suma a lo anterior ).

En resumen: este método es **lento**, pero creo que es la única solución factible en tu caso, si no deseas copiar esas imágenes a tu propio servidor.

Comment: no quiero recurrir a esto por lo que dices, es muy lento, ademas tengo otro modulo que me trae todo los productos que tengan imágenes, imagínate que tenga 700 productos con imágenes , seria super lento, y claro obviamente sirve tu solución ya que el que maneja la petición es el servidor y no el cliente. pero no es lo mas optimo, sigo investigando una solución .. muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Yo creo que podría resolverse tu problema así: `sftp://user:password@domain/ruta/imagen.png`, pero para que eso funcione necesitarías tal vez instalar un certificado de seguridad en tu servidor y habilitar el protocolo sftp

Comment: podría pero no se si google chrome desaprobara esta manera de conexion  "sftp://user:password@domain/ruta/imagen.png"..  ya que efectivamente  es insegura.